# Determine CALayer energy impact

Tags: performance, core-animation, calayer, energy

I am adding several CALayers to my application, and I while they use next to zero CPU on my machine, I notice that they tax the GPU.

Currently I use the third party app iStat Menus to monitor GPU power draw. Is there a better way to see how the CALayers utilize GPU cycles and texture memory? Ideally something like the CPU/Memory debug gauges inside Xcode.